# Add hide and slidedown events to specific Id

Tags: jquery

I'm using razor with models.

Currently I have a for loop around a partial view to create multiple versions. I have assigned the variable to the id.

**Html**

```
<div id="div-@i">
```

**Jquery**

```
if ("div:not(#div-0)") {
    $("#div-").hide();
    $("#div-").slideDown("slow");
}
```

After the 'div-', how can I select my specific element to add the events to?

**Example**

```
<div id="div-0">Information</div> <-- Already Open
<div id="div-1">Information</div> <-- Already Open
<div id="div-2">Information</div> <-- Already Open
<div id="div-3">Information</div> <-- Already Open
<div id="div-4">Information</div> <-- Not Open, Only open this div
```

Comment: I'm trying to slidedown divs with a specific id. Each div is contained in a partial view and I'm trying to get each view to slidedown on its own.

Comment: You want this kind of things  $("#div-"+i).hide();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
$("#div-").hide();
$("#div-").slideDown("slow");
```

You should use [start with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("div[id^='div-']").hide();
$("div[id^='div-']").slideDown("slow");
```

Comment: That will slide down all of them. I only want to slide down a specific one

Comment: Fixed it. Firstly used the selector to get the total number of divs with that id. Then used that value to slidedown the current div. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to hide and slideDown all the div except the `div-0`?

```
$("div:not('#div-0')").hide().slideDown("slow");
```